# trigger to capitalise inserted field

Tags: mysql, triggers

suppose for the table `student` if insert query is executed as `INSERT INTO student(id,name) VALUES (1,'sumit');`.Just after insertion of the row I want the recently inserted row's name field value to be capitalised using trigger.I searched for it every where but couldn't get working code,please some body help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the after insert and update trigger on table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER lcase_insert BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.name = LOWER(NEW.name);

CREATE TRIGGER lcase_update BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.name = LOWER(NEW.name);
```

here NEW.name is your name inserted in table.

Comment: You forgot to capitalize the name as asked in post.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. Trigger changed